# When we tell our customers that our website "supports" SAML 2.0, what would they expect?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

So, when management tells us our website needs to "support SSO through SAML 2.0", with no additional details, what are they thinking?

What will our customers expect?

Note - The is not an open website, where everyone can join. To log in you need to be a configured user in the system. The customer's admins need to create an account in our system for each user.

So we aren't going to let just anyone who has an account with an IdP in to our website. We'll have to have some mechanism for mapping a SAML identity to our users.

How would our customers expect that to work?

Comment: the customer would go to the site, be redirected to the IdP, login at their IdP and then be presented with an appropriate welcome page at the site. Or if they don't have an account, a page that says they don't have access.

Answer (score 2):

Based on hints in your question, I am going to presume that you will be acting as a service provider.

To be what I would call a "good" service provider, I would expect the following:

- You sign your AuthnRequests.
- You provide a metadata endpoint that is kept up to date with your SP metadata to include current public keys for encrypting attributes (if necessary) to be sent to you as well as validating your AuthnRequest signatures.
- You support dynamic consumption of my identity provider's metadata endpoint to keep your side of the connection up to date, especially with concern to my signing certificate.
- You expose management of my identity provider configuration inside of your service provider mechanism to my IdP administrators through a web or API interface.
- You either support a mechanism to automatically manage my users (like via SCIM or Graph or something else), or you support Just-In-Time provisioning based on an incoming assertion.
- You allow me to decide my SAML Name ID format, and that format is per-tenant. As an example, I may want to use email address as the identifier, while another IdP may want to use `sAMAccountName`. e.g., `john.doe@domain.com` vs. `johndoe`.
- You support Service-Provider-Initiated SSO. That means that the user shows up to `partner1.yourdomain.com` and get redirected for authentication to that partner's IdP, and that going to the location  `partner2.yourdomain.com` would redirect to a different IdP.

As a service provider, you should make using your service easy and secure. By shifting to SAML, it allows you to get out of the business of password and user management because you get to put that back on the identity provider. It allows your users to not have to type in a password (or more, if you're doing MFA) to use your service, removing friction caused by security. It allows you to put the onus of authenticating the user back on the organization that owns the identity.

Answer (score 0):

Your customers would expect that if they have an application that uses the SAML 2.0 client-side stack then when the application sends an AuthnRequest, they will see a login page on your site and once authenticated, the application will receive a set of assertions (claims) from your IDP via an AuthnResponse.

One of these assertions is NameID. This is the "primary key" between their system and yours. Normally this is UPN or email.

This mapping is outside of the SAML spec. There needs to be some kind of "on-boarding" for the customers.

Comment: Could as well be that they expect to delegate the auth to an actual provider like adds.

Comment: They're expecting to have to configure users in two places?